# Jenkins AD Auth with extended User search base

Tags: active-directory, authentication, jenkins

I’m trying to use a fairly large Active Directory instance to authenticate Users with Jenkins.

This works quite well with the following settings:

```
<server>ldaps://dc.example.net:636</server>
<rootDN>OU=EMEA,DC=global,DC=example,DC=net</rootDN>
<inhibitInferRootDN>false</inhibitInferRootDN>
<userSearchBase>OU=Users</userSearchBase>
<userSearch>(&amp;(c=DE)(|(company~=examplea)(company~=exampleb))(&amp;(objectClass=User)(objectClass=Person)(sAMAccountName={0})))</userSearch>
<groupSearchFilter>(&amp; (cn={0}) (objectclass=group) )</groupSearchFilter>
<groupMembershipStrategy class="jenkins.security.plugins.ldap.FromUserRecordLDAPGroupMembershipStrategy"/>
<managerDN>CN=sysauth,OU=EMEA,DC=global,DC=example,DC=net</managerDN>
<managerPasswordSecret>not-the-password</managerPasswordSecret>
<disableMailAddressResolver>false</disableMailAddressResolver>
<extraEnvVars class="linked-hash-map">
  <entry>
    <string>com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout</string>
    <string>5000000</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout</string>
    <string>5000000</string>
  </entry>
</extraEnvVars>
<displayNameAttributeName>displayname</displayNameAttributeName>
<mailAddressAttributeName>mail</mailAddressAttributeName>
<userIdStrategy class="jenkins.model.IdStrategy$CaseInsensitive"/>
<groupIdStrategy class="jenkins.model.IdStrategy$CaseInsensitive"/>
```

Note that this only works when `rootDN` contains `OU=EMEA` as seen in the working code snippet. As soon as the `rootDN` is changed to `DC=global,DC=example,DC=net` authentication fails.

Strangely it also fails if `userSearchBase` is `OU=Users,OU=EMEA` which should be equal to the settings which work.

Since there is a need to have access to groups which are somewhere located under `OU=not-EMEA,DC=global,DC=example,DC=net`, the `rootDN` has to be `DC=global,DC=example,DC=net`.

I’ve tried the following things:

- Increase `com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout` and `com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout` -> A value of `5000` would be "normal"
- Playing around with an empty `rootDN`

Comment: Did you verify that you "sysauth account (<managerDN>CN=sysauth,OU=EMEA,DC=global,DC=example,DC=net</managerDN>) has permissions to search/view beyond the OU=EMEA ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I’m able to view the whole AD using this user.

Comment: Just to be picky (sorry!) View and Search are 2 separate permissions AFAIK. Also, you say that your desired set up fails, but what error do you get exactly (e.g. LDAP error code)

Comment: Mhm, I’ll check. But shouldn’t it be the same thing to do: Root DN: `dc=global,dc=example,dc=net' with User Search DN: `OU=Users,OU=EMEA` _and_ Root DN: `OU=EMEA,dc=global,dc=example,dc=net' with User Search DN: `OU=Users`?